# Javascript discord bot mention user midsentence

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Trying to get the bot to spit out random scenario messages that also include @user midsentence.

```js
var myArray = [
  message.author + " challenges the producers, but fails to survive a single puppet",
  "Oh no, " + message.author + " got demolished by **Mr. Smiles**",
  "After gearing up in several events " + message.author + " tried to swim and drowned"
]
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
channel.message(rand)
```

The command is linking to this script and so far works, although instead of mentioning the user doing the command, it prints "undefined".

I'm fairly new to javascript, but let me know if you need more information

Comment: Use `toString()` to make a mention : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=toString Though I think this will not solve your problem. I think we need a bit more of your code to be able to find the issue.

Comment: upon changing it to message.author.toString() i recieve the following error: 
Error [javax.script.ScriptException]: TypeError: Cannot read property "toString" from undefined in <eval> at line number 1

Comment: Of course it would print that error, since `message.author` is undefined, `message.author.toString()` does not exists. That is why I edited my commend saying that we need more information

Comment: This IS the entire code ... For the command in discord, i did 
//custom setvalue NAMEOFCOMMAND https://pastebin.com/hkB85kjp 

It could be that by making it grab off pastebin, that the message.author can't be grabbed?

Comment: This cannot be the entire code, as you never defined `message` or `channel`. They must be comming from somewhere, like a function definition, in which case it would be nice to have its call.

Comment: Possibly, i'm using Arraybot to set the custom command to the pastebin-link

Comment: The use of Arraybot should be in your question, as your code is ran by it.

Comment: The code you posted is fine @Seblor's suggestion of adding `.toString()` is unnecessary, since you are already concatenating the user object with a string . The issue is you have not defined `message` or `channel` within the scope which results in `undefined.author`, hence the error.

Comment: @newbie That is what I said in my second comment. The real issue comes from the usage of Arraybot, which is something I do not know, and uses its own template strings. I actually think OP used the wrong tag, as Discord.js is not used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`message.author` is an object. If you want to get his name do `message.author.username`
If you want to mention him do: `"<@" + message.author.id + ">"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
const userAuthor = message.author.toString()
```

And then when you go to code your command:

```
message.channel.send(`The person, ${userAuthor}, is the coolest person.`)
```